# Transformation of Coordinates Question

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to transform between my Kinect's /camera_depth_optical_frame and my robot's /base_link frame. I have an Eigen::Vector4f which contains a position (x,y,z) of my point cloud in the Kinect's frame but to use the inverse kinematics services I need to transform this into the /base_link coordinate system.

Using tf_echo I know the position/rotation transformation between these two links, I just need to physically change the x,y,z values into other x,y,z values. Does anyone know a way to do this?

EDIT: Using Ivan's answer I have updated my code but get different errors now.

Here is what I have outputting to the console:

```
[ INFO] [1361845870.463119633, 1361845870.461467027]: Centroid of cloud cluster is: (-0.049989, 0.026934, 0.519591)
[ WARN] [1361845870.466575058, 1361845870.461467027]: Base to camera transform unavailable Frame id /base_link does not exist! Frames (1): 
[ INFO] [1361845870.466641668, 1361845870.461467027]: 40837646868892605535297603077151234559928972087249378994085663878457812789968315215666377820143542193373920416857156869752951414053701443003877027669632883493287576239311400849870068362363273131362348953463857542966647618830627681059177758720.000000 -0.000000 0.000000
```

The code that corresponds to this output is:

```
Eigen::Vector4f centroid; 

pcl17::compute3DCentroid(*cloud_cup,centroid);
pcl17::PointCloud<pcl17::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_cent (new pcl17::PointCloud<pcl17::PointXYZRGB>);
ROS_INFO("Centroid of cloud cluster is: (%f, %f, %f)",centroid[0],centroid[1],centroid[2]);

cloud_cent->points.resize(1);
cloud_cent->points[0].x = centroid[0];
cloud_cent->points[0].y = centroid[1];
cloud_cent->points[0].z = centroid[2];


tf::Vector3 point(centroid[0],centroid[1],centroid[2]);

tf::TransformListener listener;
tf::StampedTransform transform;
try{
    listener.lookupTransform("/base_link", "/camera_depth_optical_frame",  
                    ros::Time::now(), transform);
    }
catch (tf::TransformException ex){
    ROS_WARN("Base to camera transform unavailable %s", ex.what());
    }

tf::Vector3 point_bl = transform * point;

ROS_INFO("%f %f %f", point_bl[0],point_bl[1],point_bl[2]);
```

So it says my transformation doesn't exist but in my .urdf I have defined the joint from the base_link to the camera_link. When I run tf tf_echo /base_link /camera_depth_optical_frame I get an output of:

```
rosrun tf tf_echo /base_link /camera_depth_optical_frame
Failure at 1361845642.173521041
Exception thrown:Frame id /camera_depth_optical_frame does not exist! Frames (17): Frame /camera_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /head_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /left_rotator_link exists with parent /left_shoulder_link.
Frame /left_shoulder_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /left_upper_bicep_link exists with parent /left_tricep_link.
Frame /left_tricep_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /left_lower_forearm_link exists with parent /left_upper_forearm_link.
Frame /left_upper_forearm_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /right_rotator_link exists with parent /right_shoulder_link.
Frame /right_shoulder_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /right_upper_bicep_link exists with parent /right_tricep_link.
Frame /right_tricep_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /right_lower_forearm_link exists with parent /right_upper_forearm_link.
Frame /right_upper_forearm_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /stand_link exists with parent /base_link.

The current list of frames is:
Frame /camera_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /head_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /left_rotator_link exists with parent /left_shoulder_link.
Frame /left_shoulder_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /left_upper_bicep_link exists with parent /left_tricep_link.
Frame /left_tricep_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /left_lower_forearm_link exists with parent /left_upper_forearm_link.
Frame /left_upper_forearm_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /right_rotator_link exists with parent /right_shoulder_link.
Frame /right_shoulder_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /right_upper_bicep_link exists with parent /right_tricep_link.
Frame /right_tricep_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /right_lower_forearm_link exists with parent /right_upper_forearm_link.
Frame /right_upper_forearm_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /stand_link exists with parent /base_link.

At time 1361845643.253
- Translation: [0.070, -0.100, 0.060]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.000, 0.921, -0.390, 0.000]
                in RPY [-2.341, 0.000, -3.141]
At time 1361845643.753
- Translation: [0.070, -0.100, 0.060]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.000, 0.921, -0.390, 0.000]
                in RPY [-2.341, 0.000, -3.141]
```

All of my links have parents and joints connecting them, I don't know why I am getting that error. Furthermore, it appears like it does find some transformation between /base_link and the /camera_depth_optical_frame after a while. However, even if this is the transformation, it doesn't get recognized by my other program (the one with Ivan's answers).

Does anyone know what is going on here with my code? I will give updates to any suggestions/answers! Many thanks in advance :)

EDIT2: Adding in line:

```
    listener.waitForTransform("/base_link", "/camera_depth_optical_frame", 
                    time, ros::Duration(3));
```

Gives the error when compiling,, the line should be:

```
    listener.waitForTransform("/base_link",ros::Time::now(), "/camera_depth_optical_frame",ros::Time::now(),"/base_link",ros::Duration(3),ros::Duration(0.01));
    listener.lookupTransform("/base_link", "/camera_depth_optical_frame",  
                        ros::Time::now(), transform);
```

Indicating when you want the transform to occur and some timeout parameters, as well as the fixed frame! Problem solved, it works great now! Thanks again, Ivan

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56270/transformation-of-coordinates-question/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-26**:
The time must be a ros::Time, not a time_t.

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-02-26**:
Thanks, this worked too! I added an update but using just the four arguments worked well too. I guess it takes those as default values? Cheers!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-26**:
Actually the version with two time stamps is a different version. It should give you the same, when using the same time stamp for both times (although technically you don't do this here!)

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2013-02-26**:
Note that I added another line in the edit: "ros::Time time = ros::Time::now();". The I pass that time to both waitForTransform and lookUptransform

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-26**:
Actually, given the application he should use the time stamp of the incoming point cloud here.

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2013-02-26**:
@dornhege Yes, good point. I've revised my answer. Also this reminds me that it's not good to hardcode the frame of the cloud - it should be taken form the header. Also revised in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create a tf point from your Eigen point, query the tf server for the right transform, and then apply the transform.

Here's some code to get you started. (I haven't actually compiled this)

```
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>

// the point, in the camera frame
tf::Vector3 point(x, y, z);

// request the transform between the two frames
tf::TransformListener listener;
tf::StampedTransform transform;

// the time to query the server is the stamp of the incoming message
ros::Time time = cloud_cup->header.stamp;

// frame of the incoming message
std::string frame = cloud_cup->header.frame_id;

try{
  listener.waitForTransform("/base_link", frame, time, ros::Duration(3.0));
  listener.lookupTransform("/base_link", frame, time, transform);
}
catch (tf::TransformException ex) {
  ROS_WARN("Base to camera transform unavailable %s", ex.what());
}

// the point, in the base link frame
tf::Vector3 point_bl = transform * point;
```

If the transform doesn't change, you probably want to cache it once, and then apply it to your data without querying it over and over.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-02-25**:
Hey Ivan, thanks for the answer! The code compiled correctly but now I have strange errors at run time. I have edited the previous question. If you could provide me with some more insight that would be fantastic!

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2013-02-25**:
Check the edit, it might help. I added a waitForTransform.

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-02-26**:
I tried to add this line but I am getting a compile error now, it expects 8 arguments but only 4 are provided. Do I need to include a different header file? I put the error in the EDIT2. Thanks for all your help Ivan!

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2013-02-26**:
Revisions to answer to account for correct time and frame when querying tf server